# Azure DevOps - Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure-devops

We want to move from TFS2010 to Azure DevOps. Which was done easily after installing the VS2010 SP1

Now we need to create the Pipeline or the Build definition which is challenging since there are no Microsoft Hosted build Agents compatible for VS2010.

Can you please help on this?

Comment: If there are no hosted agents that do what you need, you'll need to set up a private agent.

Comment: Tutorials are off-topic here.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are no Hosted Agents compatible for VS2010,then using private agent would be a good choice.Also, make sure to install vs2010 on your private agent.
For details to set up a private agent,please refer to this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops).

If you feel that using a private agent is not convenient enough, you want hosted agent to be compatible with VS2010. You can raise your feature demand [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) to promote development of richer features.

**Note**: After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was able to create the private agent successfully. In the pipeline I added the projects to be built and using the private agent, but it still has issue with referencing.

Comment: Can you describe this issue in more detail?

Comment: With the private agent, BizTalk solution build was successfull